# Read device to cloud messages without CLI, device explorer

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I am trying to read D2C messages in android application. I have successfully implemented it using signalR services. But now i want to remove signalR services and read messages like device explorer or cli.

Is there a way to use sockets or any APIs to read D2C messages ?

Comment: There are many ways to read D2C messages, do you have more details on what you want to achieve with this? What's your use case?

Comment: Like i mentioned. I want to read D2C messages in mobile app built in android studio. 
Currently i am using signalR services to read D2C messages but now i want to remove signalR dependency. @MatthijsvanderVeer

Comment: Did you have any success with the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IoT Hub exposes an Event Hub endpoint. You can read messages from the built-in Event Hub endpoint with an Event Hub client. Here is an example using [Java](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-java/tree/master/iot-hub/Quickstarts/read-d2c-messages)